# Selenium : table relationship

Tags: java, selenium

Given this simple table

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>header 1</td>
                <td>header 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <tb>B</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

```
header 1    header 2    header 3    header 4
 A             B           C           D
 A1            B1          C1          D1
 A2            B2          C2          D2
```

What's the best approach to take to use selenium to handle row relationships.
Example :

1. Scenario 1, As a test, I would like to make sure that Row 1 indeed has A, B, C, D.
2. Scenario 2, As a test, I would like to make sure that A has B and not B1.

I code in Java.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the tds from the first tr and test it however you want.

```
WebElement tr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/table/tbody/tr[1]"));
List <WebElement> tds  =tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
//tds[1].getText()=="A" and so forth
for (WebElement td: tds)
{
    System.out.println(td.getText());
}
```

Not to sure about the second one yet.